# node.js Error: ENOSYS spawn when executing command line command

Tags: javascript, unix, node.js

I'm trying to run node.js under unix, and getting this error dooing that:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var commandLine = "/var/util/generate 300 300 > /tmp/barcode.png";
var childProcess;

http.createServer(function (req, res) {

var request = url.parse(req.url, true);
var action = request.pathname;

if (action == '/barcode.png') {

    console.log('executes commandLine');

    // executes 'commandLine'
    childProcess = exec(commandLine, 
        function (error, stdout, stderr) {
            sys.print('stdout: ' + stdout);
            sys.print('stderr: ' + stderr);
            var img = fs.readFileSync('/tmp/barcode.png');
            res.writeHead(200, {
                'Content-Type' : 'image/png'
            });
            res.end(img, 'binary');
            if (error !== null) {
                console.log('exec error: ' + error);
            }
        });
} else {
    res.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type' : 'text/plain'
    });
    res.end('QR Generate service reply: Please provide correct request parameter \n');
    }       
}).listen(8888);
```

console.log("QR Generate service running at http://localhost:8888");

But I'm getting:

```
Error: ENOSYS spawn
    at errnoException (child_process.js:476:11)
    at ChildProcess.spawn (child_process.js:443:11)
    at child_process.js:341:9
    at Object.execFile (child_process.js:250:15)
    at child_process.js:217:18
    at Server.<anonymous> (/base/usr/node/service.js:139:18)
    at Server.emit (events.js:70:17)
    at HTTPParser.onIncoming (http.js:1479:12)
    at HTTPParser.onHeadersComplete (http.js:102:31)
    at Socket.ondata (http.js:1375:22)
```

when it hits exec(

What is wrong?

Version of node is 0.6.4

Comment: Can you run '/var/util/generate 300 300 > /tmp/barcode.png' successfully on the command line?

Comment: Yes, it works. it creates correct file in /tmp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no solution for my problem, it was executed on a platform which doesn't support spawning on services period.